# Unable to call onPost in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to send JSON data to a razor page using POST method: `https://localhost:port/Post` and get a JSON output.

For example:

I want to pass username and email as JSON:

```
{"username":"test","email":"test@mail.com"}
```

to onPost method of Post.cshtml page: `https://localhost:44363/Post`:

```
public JsonResult OnPost([FromForm] Dictionary<String, String> FormValues)
{
    String username = FormValues["username"];
    String email = FormValues["email"];

    Dictionary<String,String> dict = new Dictionary<String, String>();

    dict.Add("username", username);
    dict.Add("email", email);

    return new JsonResult(dict);
}
```

I am calling this POST method using HttpClient in WinForms as:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

Dictionary<String, String> dict1 = new Dictionary<String, String>();

dict1.Add("username", "test");
dict1.Add("email", "test@mail.com");

String JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict1);

HttpResponseMessage Result;

Result = client.PostAsync("https://localhost:44363/Post", new StringContent(JSON, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

String json = Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Dictionary<String, String> dict2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, String>>(json);
```

But I am getting `bad request 400` error.

I have also tried `FromBody` as: `public JsonResult OnPost([FromBody] Dictionary<String, String> FormValues)` but `onPost` does not execute.

However, `OnGet` method is working fine:

```
public JsonResult OnGet()
{
    Dictionary<String, String> dict = new Dictionary<String, String>();

    dict.Add("username", "test");
    dict.Add("email", "test@mail.com");

    return new JsonResult(dict);
}
```

For `HttpClient`:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpResponseMessage Result;

Result = client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44363/Post").Result;

String json = Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Dictionary<String, String> dict2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, String>>(json);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POST handlers in [Razor Pages have request verification enabled by default](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification). This is to prevent cross site request forgery. Usually, the advice is to include the verification token within the request, but in your case, the simplest solution would be to disable the check for the token at PageModel level:

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]
public class PostModel : PageModel
{
   ...
```

Incidentally, if you are posting JSON, you need to use the `FromBody` attribute on your handler parameter, not `FromForm`.

Comment: thanks, its working fine now, but is there any other way? Instead of removing a security aspect of the website?

Comment: It only gets removed from the POST methods on that particular page, not the whole website. Ideally, you shouldn't be calling page handler methods from external applications. You should use Web API controllers to provide this kind of service, or minimal APIs if you are targeting .NET 6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0.

Comment: ok, I agree with your point. I am now trying to publish a web API controller having POST method project to https://example.com/Post path of razor page application. So, there will be 2 projects, first a razor page at https://example.com, and another a web API project with a POST controller at https://example.com/Post url that will connect with external applications. Is this the correct approach? But in future I want to add SignalR functionally, where would I add it? in razor page project at https://example.com or in web API project at https://example.com/Post?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. Not really familiar with SignalR I'm afraid.